# linear-mixed model lme4 output interpretation

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I am struggling with the output of a linear mixed model from lme4.

The outcome variable is the value column. Two mixed-effect models are a follows:

a) LME without covariates

b) LME adjusted for covariates test (factor of 2), side (factor of 2), phase (factor of 2), and location (factor of 5).

Both models correct for multiple measurements per subject (random=1|subject). Output and code below:

```
> df.fit.a <- lme(value~test, random=~1|subject, data=df)
> df.fit.b <- lme(value~test + side + phase + location, random=~1|subject, data=df)
> summary(df.fit.a)
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: df 
       AIC      BIC   logLik
  1536.032 1549.185 -764.016

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | subject
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    1.713812 11.10749

Fixed effects: value ~ test 
              Value Std.Error  DF    t-value p-value
(Intercept) -14.747  1.235912 189 -11.932083       0
testB        14.124  1.570836 189   8.991392       0
 Correlation: 
      (Intr)
testB -0.635

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-3.66331838 -0.46467384  0.01876387  0.59800981  2.20836005 

Number of Observations: 200
Number of Groups: 10     > summary(df.fit.b)
    Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
     Data: df 
           AIC      BIC    logLik
      1439.337 1471.912 -709.6683

    Random effects:
     Formula: ~1 | subject
            (Intercept) Residual
    StdDev:    2.280891  8.83572

    Fixed effects: value ~ test + side + phase + location 
                   Value Std.Error  DF   t-value p-value
    (Intercept)  -5.7530  1.908676 183 -3.014131  0.0029
    testB        14.1240  1.249559 183 11.303183  0.0000
    sideR        -0.0160  1.249559 183 -0.012805  0.9898
    phaseven     -2.6020  1.249559 183 -2.082334  0.0387
    locationi2  -13.3400  1.975727 183 -6.751945  0.0000
    locationi3  -16.3825  1.975727 183 -8.291884  0.0000
    locationi4   -8.1200  1.975727 183 -4.109879  0.0001
    locationi5   -0.5825  1.975727 183 -0.294828  0.7685
     Correlation: 
               (Intr) testB  sideR  phasvn loctn2 loctn3 loctn4
    testB      -0.327                                          
    sideR      -0.327  0.000                                   
    phaseven   -0.327  0.000  0.000                            
    locationi2 -0.518  0.000  0.000  0.000                     
    locationi3 -0.518  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.500              
    locationi4 -0.518  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.500  0.500       
    locationi5 -0.518  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.500  0.500  0.500

    Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
           Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
    -3.3119087 -0.5726300  0.1257032  0.7247609  2.2145151 

    Number of Observations: 200
    Number of Groups: 10
```

I am struggling how to report the fixed effects in model b for the location (factor of 5). It seems that every comparison is made versus location i1 and that this comparison is significant for locations i2, i3, and i4, but not i5. Is this a correct interpretation?

Also, is there a way to test whether the differences between the locations are different for test A vs test B?

I tried

```
df.fit.c <- lme(value~test_location + side + phase, random=~1|subject, data=df)
summary(df.fit.c)
    Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
     Data: df 
           AIC      BIC    logLik
      1328.783 1374.093 -650.3913

    Random effects:
     Formula: ~1 | subject
            (Intercept) Residual
    StdDev:    2.615288 6.732357

    Fixed effects: value ~ test_location + side + phase 
                           Value Std.Error  DF    t-value p-value
    (Intercept)         0.575833 1.8242559 179   0.315654  0.7526
    test_locationA_i2 -26.255000 2.1289582 179 -12.332323  0.0000
    test_locationA_i3 -30.430000 2.1289582 179 -14.293376  0.0000
    test_locationA_i4 -14.615000 2.1289582 179  -6.864860  0.0000
    test_locationA_i5  -2.435000 2.1289582 179  -1.143752  0.2543
    test_locationB_i1   0.283917 2.1378105 179   0.132807  0.8945
    test_locationB_i2  -0.141083 2.1378105 179  -0.065994  0.9475
    test_locationB_i3  -2.051083 2.1378105 179  -0.959432  0.3386
    test_locationB_i4  -1.341083 2.1378105 179  -0.627316  0.5313
    test_locationB_i5   1.553917 2.1378105 179   0.726873  0.4683
    sideR              -0.016000 0.9520991 179  -0.016805  0.9866
    phaseven           -1.419583 0.9717320 179  -1.460879  0.1458
     Correlation: 
                      (Intr) ts_A_2 ts_A_3 ts_A_4 ts_A_5 ts_B_1 ts_B_2 ts_B_3 ts_B_4 ts_B_5 sideR 
    test_locationA_i2 -0.584                                                                      
    test_locationA_i3 -0.584  0.500                                                               
    test_locationA_i4 -0.584  0.500  0.500                                                        
    test_locationA_i5 -0.584  0.500  0.500  0.500                                                 
    test_locationB_i1 -0.562  0.498  0.498  0.498  0.498                                          
    test_locationB_i2 -0.562  0.498  0.498  0.498  0.498  0.504                                   
    test_locationB_i3 -0.562  0.498  0.498  0.498  0.498  0.504  0.504                            
    test_locationB_i4 -0.562  0.498  0.498  0.498  0.498  0.504  0.504  0.504                     
    test_locationB_i5 -0.562  0.498  0.498  0.498  0.498  0.504  0.504  0.504  0.504              
    sideR             -0.261  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000       
    phaseven          -0.213  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000 -0.091 -0.091 -0.091 -0.091 -0.091  0.000

    Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
            Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
    -3.22153059 -0.46606190  0.04970901  0.52432545  2.15477603 

    Number of Observations: 200
    Number of Groups: 10
```

Based on this analysis, I could say that for there is no significant effect of side or phase on the results. For test A there is a significant difference between location i1 vs i2, i3, and i4, whereas there is no significant difference between these locations for B.

Is this a correct way of interpreting this output?

Please let me know if anything is unclear. Thank you!

Comment: Why is your first model just an intercept with a random effect? Seems a little counterintuitive. Would you want to test out the fixed effects first then fit for a random effect? http://verde.esalq.usp.br/~jorge/cursos/modelos_longitudinais/LinearMixedModels_WestWelshGalecki.pdf

Comment: Hi John, I am sorry. That was a mistake. I updated model a to value~test, random=~1|subject)

Comment: I'll give you the relevant search term: "treatment contrasts". You should find several explanations at this site and elsewhere on the internet.